# cjax codeigniter how to install

Tags: codeigniter

i have downloaded recently cajax, but I don’t undesrtand how to install.
I have this folder:

Codeigniter/
application/
  ....
system/
  ....

I have copied all file in the folder Codeigniter

that:

Codeigniter/
cjax/
  ...
ajax.php
ajaxfw.php
system/
  ...

and I written localhost/codeigniter/testing.php?test/test

and result 404 error not found. Please help me with installation I need this framework.

this is my .htaccess if need to change:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Install/Download
http://cjax.sourceforge.net/docs/installing.php

Here are the steps to get the framework installed on your site, or test installation:
1. Download the latest stable release 
2. Place the contents of the zip on the root of the site merging it with your current site. 
So you'd end up with your current structure plus:

```
     /
     cjax/
     controllers/
     ajax.php
     testing.php
```

You are set. Now lets test...
Testing your Cjax Installation

For security reasons you cannot access ajax.php directly on your browser, so we'll use testing.php to use. 
Go onto your browser and type in the url for your site, plus testing.php?test/test, eg: http://yoursite.com/testing.php?test/test 
If you see the text "Ajax View..." on your browser, that means you have successfully installed and tested the ajax framework. 
You may find the text in file controllers/test.php in function test(). If your installation was successful you may delete file testing.php.

Comment: in zip cjax, there is no file testing.php but I've solve with this url:127.0.0.1/codeigniter/ajax/test but when i click in step2 appaers this error: Invalid Function: ajax.php&tes else with this url http://127.0.0.1/codeigniter/ajax/test/test2 appaes Message: Creating default object from empty value

Filename: classes/core.class.php

Line Number: 253

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^/?ajax\/(.*)$ /ajax.php?$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|ajax)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

This worked for me.
```

Answer (score 0):

For those getting the error "Invalid Function" when clicking "View: test2" - check the URL you land on. In my case (using codeigniter), the code in test.php was missing the initial "/" so that it searches in the current directory instead of the root for ajax.php. Change the last line in /views/test.php

```
View: <a href='ajax.php?test/test2'>test2</a>
```

to

```
View: <a href='/ajax.php?test/test2'>test2</a>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Addition: I meanwhile noticed that the re-write rule of my original htaccess file didn't work correctly - that's why I had to add the slash to make it work. My mistake in the htaccess file was that I added the line `RewriteRule  ^/?ajax/(.*)$ ajax.php?$1 [NC,QSA,L]` after my index rewrite rule and this created a conflict. Once I moved the ajax.php above the index.php rewrite and its associated RewriteConditions everything works. The slash in /views/test.php as mentioned above is not required if the rewrite rule works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to this problem.

You are not taking into account that Cjax is not exclusive to CodeIgniter.  There are two different installation instructions, one Cjax universal code base that can be used on any application or website, then there is one version that integrates into CodeIgniter that is the one you are using, though you are following the instructions for the wrong installation.

There are documentations exclusive for Cjax for CodeIgniter, within CodeIgniter's wiki: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/ajax-framework-for-codeigniter

Also, some good news: The new version of Cjax,  5.9 is the universal package, but has support built-in for CodeIgniter.  This means that from there on, the installation instructions should be on the same place, or should be similar.